# Question on topic over "Aboutness theory appendix" by Stephen Yablo.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus, philosophy, sequent-calculus

i would need some help in understanding Yablo's theory of subject matter as expressed in his book "Aboutness". Yablo has uploaded an appendix on his academia.edu profile that serves as a sort of summary of the main formal issues of the book and he applies some formal concepts on propositional calculus.

The source is: https://www.academia.edu/2604116/Aboutness_Theory

Specifically, i do not understand the following passage:

9.1 Truthmakers in PC

A partial valuation ν of a given propositional language is an assignment of truth-values to some
but not necessarily all of the language’s atoms. A partial model of A  is a partial valuation each of whose classical extensions makes X true. A minimal model χ of X is a partial model of X none of whose proper submodels are partial models of X. (Notation: α is a minimal model of A, β is a minimal model of B, and so on.) A truthmaker for sentence X is a minimal model of X. A falsemaker for X is a minimal model of ¬X, aka a minimal counter model of X. A truthmaker for X in ν is a minimal model χ of X such that χ⊆ν. A falsemaker for X in ν is a minimal countermodel χ of X such that χ⊆ν."

a) What are the classical extensions of a partial valuation on a sentence A in a given propositional language? I think they should be considered as all the valuations that assign to a given atomic formula p the value"true", but correct me if it is wrong.

Shouldn't a truthmaker be a set of valuations in which the sentence X is true, rather then a single valutation that gives X the value "true"?

b) What does it mean that a minimal model for X is a partial model that does not have any proper sub-models that are partial model of X? What is a proper sub model of a partial valutation?

In this case, I thought that a minimal model should be a set of valuations that assign X the value "true"   and it is the smallest such set, not having any set with valuations that is included in that minimal set. But I think I still do not get the point, so I ask you about this.

10.1 Aboutness in PC

X ’s subject matter is the m whose cells are made up, for each minimal model χ of X, of the classical models “above” (including) χ. X ’s subject anti-matter is the m whose cells are the classical models above X ’s minimal.

c) What does it mean that m has as cells the classical models "above" each minimal model of X? Inuitively I thought that a subject matter could be considered the set that has as elements all the sets that contain valutations that makes X "true", but I do not get the sense of introducing models "above" a certain minimal model for X

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

See 1.1.: $v$ is a "classical valuation" if it satisfies the rule for negation: $v(¬A)=\text T \text {  iff  } v(A)=\text F$, that means that: "A proposition $A$ is true in world w iff $w \in A$, otherwise false".

A partial model of $A$ is a partial valuation that can be extended (using classical truth tables) to be a model of $A$, i.e. to satisfy A.

A *truthmaker* is a model that is minimal.

See [Aboutness](https://books.google.it/books?id=kXCYDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA61), page 61:

> "Minimal models can be construed, if we like, as van Fraassen–style facts: $\{ p, \lnot q \}$ is the valuation that assigns truth to $p$ and falsity to $q$."

This correspond to the valuation $v(p)=\text T$ and $v(q)=\text F$ and is a model for the formula $(p \land \lnot q)$.

It is minimal because if we remove one of the two assignment, what is left is no more a model of formula $(p \land \lnot q)$, because we have not enough information to compute the truth value of the formula.

Now, using this simple example, we have that:

> $v_1(p)=\text T$ is a *partial valuation* [an assignment of truth-values to some but not necessarily all of the language's atoms].

It is not a *partial model* of $(p \land \lnot q)$ because the extension $z$ of $v$ such that $z(p)=v(p)$ and $z(q)=\text T$ does not make $A$ true.

Every extension $w$ of $v$ that is a *model* must contain $w(p)=\text T$ and $w(q)=\text F$.

Thus, $v_1$ such that $v_1(p)=\text T, v_1(q)=\text F, v_1(r)=\text T$ is a partial model of formula $(p \land \lnot q)$.

The minimal one is $v'(p)=\text T, v'(q)=\text F$.

Comment: Thanks, i write here just to be sure i have understood: a classical extension for sentence "A" would be the value v assign to A; in the case of partial model of A, that value is always "T"; sub-models are valuations for one or more components of the sentence "A". For χ to be a minimal model for "A", it has to assign to A the value "T" and there must not be valuations for a component of A that assignt to A the value "T". Sorry if there is some confusion in my discourse.

Comment: Thanks, so the minimal model for p AND not-q must leave all the formulas of the propositional language that are not p or q undefined?   And, for instance, for the formula p or q a partial model would be v(p)=t,  v(q)=f, v(y)=t, while the two minimal models would be z(p)=t and y(q)=t or should we include also the minimal model n(p)=t, n(q)=t?